# flowtyping a higher order function for wrapping functions of arbitrary arity (and mutating the parameter and return types)

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a function `nilGuard` that wraps another function (let's call it `f`) and returns a function which, if any of its arguments are `undefined` or `null` will return a default value (which is `null` by default) and will otherwise return the result of applying its arguments to `f`:

```
function isNil(value) {
  return value === undefined || value === null
}

export function nilGuard(f, defaultValue = null) {
  return (...args) => (args.some(isNil) ? defaultValue : f.apply(this, args))
}
```

I've tried [adding types](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVUCuA7AxgFwEs5sxCBnAOUJgAoA3AQxkwFMBKALjACM44YrRqQCkuABatcAa3JgA3qjBgATq3yYVpJi1ZgAvIbDZMMGGAA+FsDrYGjOACasohbK0eoAvumDAwACoAngAOevhwqqwhauSs2Phg+JJgWAnEpDysbgDmYAgqjCFhjmC0wqXJeiR6WblRGloe7Kh+YACCZHJVSaHhmCGCtAD8LW0ASl1JKWqNpPh9qAthYABiADztADRg4wB8BmUAdCeMKjnk3O3sBgfjrf7BK2kEGdOMifiF2ORQcCoAWzkjDAOUI9HivRWATICUiIOwNBgjB4gjKJjMYH+YCcLjczRsrBU5AySz6YGoZhRaP0YHWAT2tBu+gOwxh1gxMAeYAAEoQcpIVFiVM4hctwuIPklND8wCCNIM9G4InLpYqsVBjEjqaw5HBNT1-vy3MwobqjmSVpTkajdZsDrSACQBAaCACyRU2O2tOr2vn8nQo03C5P1wbl526rtY3MmQZ6sxlZo1qW5ABEpj1xSmes4oIxTIlbDGXkQSFqYABxTBnRxe3Y7NOMqDcDbbXZ7HZ5gswfAANWYbG4GdpnK4a3WPtt5HtO0m1ibCiUDSTtBORzOFyuzIO5UjR3IcABrFoFEpN2GYG7hYHujA3CgG+KMCCtGSFB2m-I7BaPgwOFecsYjxAAPWgQg+cRuHIL5cnHGCVHqRRlETLQwAAA3EfB8BCS4-FYEDGABRUjlwI9HXkCDki8dDvHQUs3kYRxHFoEDuBMAEshUHYgnYzBOKJccOK4pcUPUJMQLAABqMAgjo1AyJ+RIchrEUPAABTUVw2LKYYEPqDlTBgHcyn07A8kMsxmQrata3ArTCBAlpFJg0FVOcRx2mYgB1QhkjTFwe3wbgRmEolLGMIydmGMKhUs4zbkigShVHGhbJFcpmJ2AAGFogA):

```
function isNil(value): boolean %checks {
  return value === null || value === undefined
}

// Type to represent the funtion being wrapped (and the one being returned)
// A is the type tuple(?)
// R is the return type
type F<A, R> = (...args: A) => R
// Type function that transforms a given type T into a nillable (null or undefined) version
type Nillable = <T>() => ?T | null
// Higher order type that turns a tuple into a tuple of nillables of the original types.
type Nillables<A> = $TupleMap<A, Nillable>

// A is the type of the args tuple
// R is the return type of f
// D is the type of the default value
function nilGuard<A, R, D>(f: F<A, R>, defaultValue: D = null): F<Nillables<A>, R | D> {
  return (...args: A) => (args.some(isNil) ? defaultValue : f.apply(this, args))
}
```

Unfortunately, flow is giving the following errors:

```
19: function nilGuard<A, R, D>(f: F<A, R>, defaultValue: D = null): F<Nillables<A>, R | D> {
                                                             ^ null. This type is incompatible with
19: function nilGuard<A, R, D>(f: F<A, R>, defaultValue: D = null): F<Nillables<A>, R | D> {
                                                         ^ D
20:   return (...args: A) => (args.some(isNil) ? defaultValue : f.apply(this, args))
                              ^ call of method `some`. Method cannot be called on
20:   return (...args: A) => (args.some(isNil) ? defaultValue : f.apply(this, args))
                              ^ A
20:   return (...args: A) => (args.some(isNil) ? defaultValue : f.apply(this, args))
                                                                              ^ A. This type is incompatible with
20:   return (...args: A) => (args.some(isNil) ? defaultValue : f.apply(this, args))
                                                                              ^ $Iterable
Property `@@iterator` is incompatible:
20:   return (...args: A) => (args.some(isNil) ? defaultValue : f.apply(this, args))
                                                                              ^ property `@@iterator` of `$Iterable`. Property not found in
20:   return (...args: A) => (args.some(isNil) ? defaultValue : f.apply(this, args))
                                                                              ^ A
```

As far as I understand it, this comes down to two issues:

1. The args tuple, `A`, being treated as non-iterable. This is either a result of calling `some()` on it, or the spread operator later on - both should be safe on tuples, I believe.
2. The typing of `D`, the default value. Ideally, `type D = null` would be the default case, but if I invoke `nilGuard` with a second argument, `D` should gain the type of that second argument. Flow seems to assume that my type parameter D is itself not a nullable type.

I've included two function defintions at the bottom of [the attempt that I linked to earlier](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVUCuA7AxgFwEs5sxCBnAOUJgAoA3AQxkwFMBKALjACM44YrRqQCkuABatcAa3JgA3qjBgATq3yYVpJi1ZgAvIbDZMMGGAA+FsDrYGjOACasohbK0eoAvumDAwACoAngAOevhwqqwhauSs2Phg+JJgWAnEpDysbgDmYAgqjCFhjmC0wqXJeiR6WblRGloe7Kh+YACCZHJVSaHhmCGCtAD8LW0ASl1JKWqNpPh9qAthYABiADztADRg4wB8BmUAdCeMKjnk3O3sBgfjrf7BK2kEGdOMifiF2ORQcCoAWzkjDAOUI9HivRWATICUiIOwNBgjB4gjKJjMYH+YCcLjczRsrBU5AySz6YGoZhRaP0YHWAT2tBu+gOwxh1gxMAeYAAEoQcpIVFiVM4hctwuIPklND8wCCNIM9G4InLpYqsVBjEjqaw5HBNT1-vy3MwobqjmSVpTkajdZsDrSACQBAaCACyRU2O2tOr2vn8nQo03C5P1wbl526rtY3MmQZ6sxlZo1qW5ABEpj1xSmes4oIxTIlbDGXkQSFqYABxTBnRxe3Y7NOMqDcDbbXZ7HZ5gswfAANWYbG4GdpnK4a3WPtt5HtO0m1ibCiUDSTtBORzOFyuzIO5UjR3IcABrFoFEpN2GYG7hYHujA3CgG+KMCCtGSFB2m-I7BaPgwOFecsYjxAAPWgQg+cRuHIL5cnHGCVHqRRlETLQwAAA3EfB8BCS4-FYEDGABRUjlwI9HXkCDki8dDvHQUs3kYRxHFoEDuBMAEshUHYgnYzBOKJccOK4pcUPUJMQLAABqMAgjo1AyJ+RIchrEUPAABTUVw2LKYYEPqDlTBgHcyn07A8kMsxmQrata3ArTCBAlpFJg0FVOcRx2mYgB1QhkjTFwe3wbgRmEolLGMIydmGMKhUs4zbkigShVHGhbJFcpmJ2AAGFogA) to illustrate the kinds of function type transformations I expect this function to achieve:

```
function prefix(path: string): string {
  return `https://example.com${path}`
}

function add(x: number, y: number): number {
  return x + y
}

const guardedPrefix: (?string | null) => (string | null) = nilGuard(prefix)
const guardedAddWithDefault: (?number | null, ?number | null) => number = nilGuard(add, 0)
```

All help/suggestions appreciated :)

Comment: Please put the code of your typing attempts in the question itself, not just a link to the code

Comment: Sorry, I thought it might be more use to link the flowtype testing area... I've included my attempt at the typings in the question now along with the sample wrappings and their types that I'd hope to get out of this function.

Comment: I think you will need to use `defaultValue: Nillable<D> = null` to fix the second problem.

Comment: I believe Flow is trying to tell you that `args` (which is known to be an array of something) cannot be typed with an arbitrary `A` type parameter

Comment: @Bergi don't see why, since `type Foo = [string, number, Object]` is possible...

Comment: @Bergi and Nillable<D> wouldn't be good enough for when someone *does* provide a non-nillable default value, I want the type to reflect that it will come out that way - see the example of `guardedAddWithDefault`.

Comment: I meant something like `type F<A implements Tuple, R> = (...args: A) => R` - `A` must be an array (or tuple) type and not something arbitrary. That said, I have no idea of flow's type system specifically :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have identified the sources of the Flow errors. I'd like to elaborate on why those are problems.

> The args tuple, A, being treated as non-iterable. This is either a result of calling some() on it, or the spread operator later on - both should be safe on tuples, I believe.

You have specified that the type of the `args` tuple is `A`, and you have not put any constraints on the variable `A`. Flow considers that to mean that `A` could be assigned any type, including non-iterable types. You are correct that `args` is iterable. All that you have to do is to specify a constraint for `A` that is compatible with rest arguments lists. That could be `A: Array<mixed>`. But you don't actually have to select the constraint yourself - you can simply indicate that there is a constraint and let Flow infer what the constraint should using the `*` annotation:

```
function nilGuard<A: *, R, D>
```

> The typing of D, the default value. Ideally, type D = null would be the default case, but if I invoke nilGuard with a second argument, D should gain the type of that second argument. Flow seems to assume that my type parameter D is itself not a nullable type.

This is essentially the same problem: you did not put any constraints on `D`, which tells Flow that `D` could take on any type including non-nullable types. You can fix that by changing the type of `defaultValue` like this:

```
defaultValue: ?D = null
```

That tells Flow that regardless of the type that is chosen for `D`, `defaultValue` has the additional possibility of being `null`. But I would approach this problem a bit differently. (More on that below.)

There are a couple more problems:

The definition of `Nillable<T>` must annotate the argument position with the type `T`. That definition should look like this:

```
type Nillable = <T>(_: T) => ?T
```

If `T` is not given in the argument position then there is no way for Flow to relate the return type to the input type.

In the definition of `Nillable<T>` you use the type `?T | null` which is redundant: `?T` is shorthand for `T | void | null`, where `void` is the type for `undefined`.)

So here is how I would do it. If the caller specifies `defaultValue`, you want `nilGuard` to return that value in the default case. But if the caller does not provide `defaultValue` then the default return value should be `null` (or `undefined`, which would be more idiomatic). The cleanest way to accomplish this is to use an overloaded signature for the type of `nilGuard`. You want `nilGuard` to behave differently depending on the number of arguments that are provided. So you have one signature that looks like this:

```
function nilGuard<A: *, R, D>(f: F<A, R>, defaultValue: D): F<Nillables<A>, R | D>
```

And a distinct signature that looks like this:

```
function nilGuard<A: *, R>(f: F<A, R>): F<Nillables<A>, ?R>
```

(BTW I think that your use of `$TupleMap` to define `Nillables` is quite nifty!)

At runtime these are the same function. But Flow can track overloaded signatures and select the appropriate signature for call site based on the arguments that are given. Unfortunately declaring an overloaded function is a bit awkward because Javascript does not have a native overload syntax. The easiest option is to use Flow `declare` statements to declare all of the function signatures, and write the actual definition separately:

```
declare function nilGuard<A: *, R, D>(f: F<A, R>, defaultValue: D): F<Nillables<A>, R | D>
declare function nilGuard<A: *, R>   (f: F<A, R>): F<Nillables<A>, ?R>

function nilGuard(f, defaultValue) {
  return (...args) => args.some(isNil) ? defaultValue : f.apply(this, args)
}
```

The overloaded signatures allow Flow to track whether a return value might be `undefined`, or whether the type is the exact union of the underlying function return type and the type of `defaultValue`. If for example `D` is the same type as `R` then you can save yourself some `undefined` checks.

An unfortunate effect of using `declare` is that Flow will not check the definition of `nilGuard` itself for correctness. But this will get you the type-checking behavior that you want when `nilGuard` is called. Another form for overloaded functions that does internally check the function definition looks like this:

```
type NilGuard =
  & (<A: *, R, D>(f: F<A, R>, defaultValue: D) => F<Nillables<A>, R | D>)
  & (<A: *, R>   (f: F<A, R>) => F<Nillables<A>, ?R>)

const nilGuard: NilGuard = (f, defaultValue) =>
  (...args) => args.some(isNil) ? (defaultValue: any) : f.apply(null, args)
```

That works because Flow treats an overloaded function as an intersection of multiple function types. But the behavior of `nilGuard` is sufficiently tricky that I was not able to get this form to type-check.